# AngularJS $httpBackend - "No more request expected" error

Tags: angularjs

It seems [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EgMpe/8/) is working solution that shows how to work with `$httpBacked` http://jsfiddle.net/EgMpe/8/

But for my case:

**routes**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.

    when('/',  {templateUrl: 'partials/user-list.html'}).
```

...

**faked service:**

```
app.run(function($httpBackend) {

        var users = [{"id":1,"name":"bob","email":"bob@bobs.com"}, {"id":2,"name":"bob2","email":"bob2@bobs.com"}]

        $httpBackend.whenGET('/rest/users').respond(function(method,url,data) {
            console.log("Getting users");
            return [200, users, {}];
        });
    });
```

..

**real service:**

```
services.factory('Users', function($resource){
    return $resource('/rest/users', {}, {
        get:        {method: 'GET', isArray:true}
    });
});
```

I have **error** when go to my "/" route that redirects me to `user-list.html` page:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET partials/user-list.html No more request
>   expected
>       at $httpBackend .../mysite/public/angular/libs/angular-1.2.0/angular-mocks.js:1060:9)

**Question1:** Does `httpBackend` prevent doing any other `http` request?

I tried to use **passThrough** method to let http hit real server side:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/mysite\//).passThrough();
```

But this does not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah.. Sorry I just was wrong with my RegEx:

if type this `$httpBackend.whenGET(/partials/).passThrough();`

Then all start working.

So, I got my lesson: don't forget to put: **passThrough();** with right **RegEx**.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently experiencing the same exception. I see you solved it with the `passThrough()` function. But do you know why it is loading/GETting the `user-list.html page` ? In your test you mock the `$httpBackend.whenGET` so why the loading of the html file?

Comment: As far as I remember it was loading the page because I did mistake in mocked URL, so instead of hitting mocked URL hit real one - do it loaded the real page. Tried.

Answer (score 9):

Using `$httpBackend` you have to specify in advance all request you are going to perform. Maybe this short excerpt from `Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS` will clarify why:

> The verifyNoOutstandingExpectation method verifies that all the expected
>   calls were made ($http methods invoked and responses flushed), while the
>   verifyNoOutstandingRequest call makes sure that code under test didn't trigger
>   any unexpected XHR calls. Using those two methods we can make sure that the code
>   under the test invokes all the expected methods and only the expected ones.