# Angular $httpBackend error "No more request expected"

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, httpbackend

Below is my controller,

```
function adminController($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.enabledRights = [];
$http.get('user/rights').success(function(data) {
        $scope.enabledRights = data;

}).error(function() {
        $scope.enabledRights = [];
});
}

angular.module('queueManagerApp')
.controller('adminController',
    ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$filter', '$window',    adminController]);
```

Below is my test-case for above controller

```
'use strict';

describe('Admin controller', function () {
    var $controller;
    var $httpBackend;
    var $scope;
    var testData = {
      query: {
        input: ['XYZ']

      }
    }

beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp' ));

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
$controller = _$controller_;
$scope = {};
$httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
}));

describe('http test ( Get user rights details -1 )', function () {
 it('should fetch user details', function() {
     $httpBackend.when('GET', '/user/rights')
     .respond(testData);

     $controller('adminController',{ $scope: $scope });

     //$scope.isEnabled();
     $httpBackend.flush();
     expect($scope.enabledRights).toEqual(testData.query.input);
 });
});

describe('http test (get User rights - 2 )', function () {
it('should fetch user rights details',inject(function($http) {
    var $scope = {};

    $http.get('/user/rights')
         .success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
             $scope.enabledRights = data;
         }).error(function(data, status,headers,config) {
             $scope.enabledRights = "Error";
         });

    $httpBackend
     .when('http://localhost:9999/user/rights')
     .respond(200, { enabledRights : 'XYZ' });

     $httpBackend.flush();

     expect($scope.enabledRights).toEqual ( { enabledRights : 'XYZ' }    
);   
}));
});  
});
```

When I run test case I am getting below error, I am not getting how to resolve this issue. Please suggest me to resolve the same.

```
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-    
manager-client/test/spec/controllers/admin.js".
WARN [web-server]: 404: /queuemanager/getUserName?token=undefined
WARN [web-server]: 404: /user/clientorgs
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) Admin controller http test ( Get user     
rights details -1 ) should fetch user details FAILED
Error: Unexpected request: GET user/rights
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-  
client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1211)
    at sendReq (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-  
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10334)
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-  
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10045
    at processQueue (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14567)
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-   
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14583
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15846
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15657
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1509
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-  
client/test/spec/controllers/admin.js:30 
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) Admin controller http test (get User   
rights - 2 ) should fetch user rights details FAILED
Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:9999/user/rights
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1211)
    at sendReq (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10334)
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10045
    at processQueue (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14567)
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14583
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15846
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15657
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-  
client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1509
    at /home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/test/spec/controllers/admin.js:50
    at invoke (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager-
client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4450)
    at workFn (/home/madhugowda/Madhu/gitrepo/queue-manager- 
client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2404)
undefined
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 (2 FAILED) (0.002 secs    
/ 0.028 secs)
```

Comment: You've configured it to expect `'http://localhost:9999/user/rights'` but you're only requesting `'/user/rights'`. `$httpBackend` is quite literal about the arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432482/angularjs-httpbackend-no-more-request-expected-error

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the reply. i have changed to  http://localhost:9999/user/rights, but still i am getting same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to put the expectations before the $http.get call?

Answer (score 0):

Until you add request for the particular URL you mocked , till then you will receive this error

- you have done only mocking
- Make sure you are doing particular URL call in your code
- Add require to particular call if you are loading some file like
  readJson or `require("file.json")`